# Web Animation technologies

Tags: animations

Nice to be here. 
Can anyone tell me what kind of animation technology was used on the [adguard site](https://adguard.com/de/welcome.html)

I tried to sift through the code but could not find a hint.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

What is used is the [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web) software that exports to SVG+JS

> Lottie is a mobile library for Web, and iOS that parses Adobe After Effects animations exported as json with Bodymovin and renders them natively on mobile!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the downvote. Still. It is customary to explain why.